# copy() function returns true, but the file is not updated in php

Tags: php

In my PHP app, `copy()` function works fine, but is not working in server.

```
$new_file = 'some_new_file';
$old_file = 'existing_file';
if ( copy($new_file, $old_file) ) {
        return new JsonResponse(array('status' => true,'success' => 'File saved successfully'));
        //print_r("Copy success!");
    }else{
        return new JsonResponse(array('status' => false,'success' => 'Problem in saving file'));
    }
```

It is returning status as `true`, but `$old_file` is not updated.

In this even copy() returns true, because the response what I'm getting is

```
{"status":true,"success":"File saved successfully"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you swapped the arguments to `copy` around. From [the documentation on php.net](http://php.net/copy):

```
<?php
$file = 'example.txt';
$newfile = 'example.txt.bak';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}
```

As you can see, the source file is specified first, the destination second.

---

Specific to your code, try changing

```
copy($new_file, $old_file)
```

to

```
copy($old_file, $new_file)
```

Comment: $old_file is a destination file, and new_file is another file and I have to copy the content from $new_file to $old_file.

Answer (score 1):

once ckeck this file permission 777 need for this

Comment: Permission of both the files is 777